# ffmpeg video not working in JWPlayer

Tags: ffmpeg, jwplayer

I have created a video from mixing an audio and a video. By using

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i a.mp3  -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0.0 -map 1.0 -shortest output.mp4
```

Its working fine in VLC player but no sound in JWPlayer. Its also buffering the whole video before starting the video.
How to resolve this issue .

Here is output of ffmpeg command.

```
 FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
 built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
 configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --    mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-  libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable- libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 -- enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared -- enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
 libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
 libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
 libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
 libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
 libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
 libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
 libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
 Metadata:
   major_brand     : mp42
   minor_version   : 0
   compatible_brands: isommp42
 Duration: 00:01:17.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 614 kb/s
   Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x360, 515 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc
   Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 96 kb/s
 [mp3 @ 0x1258e440]max_analyze_duration reached
 [mp3 @ 0x1258e440]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
 Input #1, mp3, from 'a.mp3':
  Metadata:
   TSSE            : Lavf52.64.2
  Duration: 00:06:53.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
 File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
 Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 640x360, q=2-31, 515 kb/s, 60k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, 64 kb/s
  Stream mapping:
    Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
    Stream #1.0 -> #0.1
  Press [q] to stop encoding
  frame= 2322 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5526kB time=77.48 bitrate= 584.3kbits/s    
  video:4878kB audio:605kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.777738%
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: For the buffering part you probably need to move the moov atom to the beginning of the movie. See this https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-3 (-movflags faststart part)

Comment: You should include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: -movflags faststart part is giving error , Unrecognized option 'movflags' may be because of older version.

Comment: `0.6.5` is ancient. Please use a recent version. [Compile ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) or simply [download a build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Also, a link to the not-working file would be useful.